# Issues Trying to Run CakePHP2 Tests on Console

Tags: shell, testing, console, cakephp-2.0

In my development environment, I load CakePHP via Composer to the Vendor directory.  The site runs fine as well as the tests in the browser.  In the console, I am able to generate MVC, test cases, fixtures, etc.  What I am unable to do it run my tests on the console. `./Console/cake test app Controller/OrdersController` produces `Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.`  I do have my `$test` DATABASE_CONFIG set up in `database.php` and I imagine if that was incorrect, I would be unable to run my tests in the browser.  I am running version 2.5.8 and am using the latest `cake.php` file with the `$composerInstall` variable as shown https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/05709908a7f529d4e49534b687b0f31884e95132/app/Console/cake.php  Can anyone suggest with I should further be looking at to fix this and run my tests on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug into this further and found my issue.  It was actually in my Fixture files.  In a couple of them I was specifying the model and connection keys.  Removing those made my tests work on the command line and no more Mysql missing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to enable the PDO module for PHP-CLI, they have different configurations.

On Linux they are kept at /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

you should just create a symbolic link to ../../mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini or whatever it is on your system.

Under Windows it will be in the php.ini.

Update:

You should also check that you have $this->default defined in your database.php.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I am running a Linux VM.  I checked the sym links in that folder and that sym link exists along with others.

Comment: on the console try doing `php -i | grep pdo` and see if you have PDO extensions out. Also see my edit!